# Is it permitted to omit eating suhoor? Or to eat it after maghrib instead of early in the morning?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

This is a question for people who live across equator, who has to work in morning, and who has maghrib really late and Saher very early, only 2-3 hours difference. Some people say that if you do Saher, before time it is permissible, as one have to wake up early to commute.

E.g. if maghrib happens at 23:00 and saher happens at 3am or 2am. I can eat with intention of Saher after 23:00. 
Is it valid to do something like that?

As I commute really far and have good walking distance.

Comment: Well basically there's no problem from a shari'a PoV, but you must take care for the needs if your body (stomach etc.) and eat and drink at separate times.

Answer (score 1):

Eating so early will not count as Suhoor since by definition it is the meal that is eaten before dawn.

However a fast is valid without the Suhoor (pre-dawn meal), although there is Barkah (blessing) in taking the Suhoor, and its Mustahab (recommended).

So you can skip Suhoor, or take it hours before its time and the fast will remain valid. If you want to take it at its proper time, you can take a snack with you while you commute and eat it at the right time by checking your watch etc.

---

In Saheeh Bukhari there is a chapter titled

> باب بركة السحور من غير إيجاب لأن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم وأصحابه
> واصلوا ولم يذكر السحور
>
> Sahur is a blessing but it is not compulsory, because the Prophet and
> his Companions observed Wisal and did not mention Suhoor.

This chapter lists the following Hadith:

> [Saheeh Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/31) The Prophet (ﷺ) fasted for days continuously; the
> people also did the same but it was difficult for them. So, the
> Prophet (ﷺ) forbade them (to fast continuously for more than one day).
> They slid, "But you fast without break (no food was taken in the
> evening or in the morning)." The Prophet (ﷺ) replied, "I am not like
> you, for I am provided with food and drink (by Allah).
>
> [Saheeh Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/32) The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Take Suhur as there is a
> blessing in it."

And Ibn Hajar, in [Fath Al Bar](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=3517&bk_no=52&flag=1)i, links it to the following Hadith:

> [Saheeh Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/72) Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) forbade Al-Wisal in fasting.
> So, one of the Muslims said to him, "But you practice Al- Wisal. O
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)!" The Prophet (ﷺ) replied, "Who amongst you is
> similar to me? I am given food and drink during my sleep by my Lord."
> So, when the people refused to stop Al-Wisal (fasting continuously),
> the Prophet (ﷺ) fasted day and night continuously along with them for
> a day and then another day and then they saw the crescent moon (of the
> month of Shawwal). The Prophet (ﷺ) said to them (angrily), "If It (the
> crescent) had not appeared, I would have made you fast for a longer
> period." That was as a punishment for them when they refused to stop
> (practicing Al-Wisal).

The argument is that the Prophet and the Sahabah observed Wisal (continous fasting for days without a meal at nights), and whereas this was discouraged the fast was considered valid ... since Wisal is valid, not eating Sahoor is valid since Sahoor would interrupt the Wisal.

---

From [Islamic Jurisprudence According To The Four Sunni School](https://archive.org/stream/IslamicJurisprudenceAccordingToTheFourSunniSchoolsAlFiqhalaAlMadhahibAlArbaah#page/n803/mode/2up):

> **Desirable** practices associated with fasting:
>
> (3) **Taking a pre-dawn meal**, however light, even if it consists of
> nothing but a sip of water. This ruling is based on the words of the
> Prophet:"Partake of a pre-dawn meal, for it holds a blessing." **The
> time period during which the pre-dawn meal is to be taken commences
> with the beginning of the latter half of the night**. The latter one
> partakes of the pre-dawn meal, the better, such that there is no doubt
> concerning the break of dawn.

The book does not seem to mention any disagreement among the four major schools on this issue.